# proper setup for substrate archive node

Tags: substrate-archive

pruning=archive will keep all the blocks in the nodes databases. As the blocks are there in the archive-node then do we really need a separate parallel postgres db as suggested in https://docs.substrate.io/reference/command-line-tools/archive/ ??

So overall what should be the setup of an archive node apart from db ? Also, I want to use subsquid archive in the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the node uses a database (ParityDb or RocksDb). However the data in that database is stored as key-value and is opaque where as with substrate-archive the data is stored in a postgres database according to a schema:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/blob/master/SubstrateArchiveSchema.pdf

And as you can see the data is not opaque.

Another resource that may be helpful is the README:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive#substrate-archive

Comment: Do you mean in substrate-archive node blocks are there in RocksDb/ParityDb (in opaque format) as well as in postgres??

Comment: No, in substrate-archive there is only postgres

Comment: Make sense. Thank you @Bruno. A followup question : will a new archive node be able to sync from this substrate-archive? I am asking this to confirm that whether its still a blockchain node or its become an explorer backend database !!

Comment: No as substrate-archive is not a node its an indexing engine with a postgres database...

Comment: Okay got it. So we must have one or rather should have at least one substrate node with pruning=archive in the network to serve any upcoming node or archive  to facilitate with sync service? Or in case if re-indexing is required in then also node with pruning=archive will be needed.

Comment: Yes and if you want to re-index then you will need that synced archive node.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!